# Consume restful API get method with content(body) or more than one parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, xamarin.forms, getasync

This is my API method and it takes 3 parameters from body

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<EnCurso>> GetIdCondByDTRuta(EnCurso encurso)
            {
                var db = dbConnection();
                return await db.QueryAsync<EnCurso>("select * from public.tb_encurso where to_timestamp('" + encurso.inicio+ "','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') between inicio AND fin and idruta = " + encurso.idruta+ " and idbus = "+ encurso.idbus + " and estado=true;", new { encurso.inicio, encurso.idruta, encurso.idbus });
            }

    [HttpGet("GetIdCondByDTRuta")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> GetIdCondByDTRuta([FromBody] EnCurso encurso)
            {
                return Ok(await _encursoRepository.GetIdCondByDTRuta(encurso));
            }
```

When testing on Postman from body works fine.
[image: Postman test]

But then I don't know how to send content from the app consuming the API.
I tried adding the parameters in the URI, like this

```
    var _URI = "http://XXX.XXX.0.XX:4XXX8/api/encurso/GetIdCondByDTRuta.json?inicio:" + encurso.inicio + "&idruta:" + encurso.idruta + "&idbus:" + encurso.idbus;
                HttpResponseMessage result = await client.GetAsync(_URI);
```

Doesn't work. I tried search for a httpclient method that takes the Uri and content, as the post do, but GET methods don't have the option

[image: Post content example]

Comment: GET methods shouldn't accept body parameters.  It would make more sense to modify your server method to accept three distinct parameters that you can pass on the querystring.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP Get methods should not contain a body as referenced in this thread: [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body).

When creating Get API methods it is better to use [FromQuery]-[FromQueryAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromqueryattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0) this will bind the data to primitive types. So you will need 3 separate parameters. If you want to bind to an object you will need to create a custom ModelBinder.

This doc from Microsoft goes through your options when trying to bind data in an ASP.Net core/5 API [Binding source parameter inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#binding-source-parameter-inference)